# How can I avoid duplicate usernames while joining 2 tables

Tags: mysql, find-in-set

I have two tables related to user information:
Table 1(Users) contains columns like id,username and email 
Table 2(details) contains columns like user_id,degree_name and degree
when I am joining these two tables, result I am getting is:

```
name         degree_name      degree

john doe      Metric          Science
john doe      Fsc             Engineering  
john doe      Bsc             BSCS
herald        Metric          Science
Matt          Metric          Science
```

In above records "john doe" is repeating 3 times. what should be not expected result.
The result I want here is and also I know can be achievable by using find_in_set() is:

```
0: {name: john doe
    details: {0: {degree: "Science",degree_name: "Metric"}
              1: {degree: "Fsc",degree_name: "Engineering  "}
              2: {degree: "Science",degree_name: "BSCS"}}}
1: {name: herald
    details: {0: {degree: "Science",degree_name: "Metric"}}}
2: {name: Matt
    details: {0: {degree: "Science",degree_name: "Metric"}}}
```

Is there anybody who guide me for the right query?

Comment: Mysql (and sql generally) is not designed to pretty print if you have an application (eg php) you should do it there.

Comment: Yes I know that this is achievable through php but the thing is, Mysql will get all records then we will loop and get records from there. that is not good

Comment: Here you can used group_concat()

Comment: Also it’s possible to generate JSON data directly in MySQL, which i think you are after here?

Answer (score 0):

You can use group_concat for degree and degree_name. eg . :

```
SELECT name, group_concat(degree), group_concat(degree_name) FROM Table1,Table2 WHERE Table1.id=Table.User_id. GROUP BY Table1.id
```

It will give you result with one row for one user.

Jon Doe   |   Metric,Fsc,Bsc      |      Science,Eng,BCSc.

Comment: I know group_concat() will combine records into one row but as mentioned above, I want an array like details for user details table.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  u.username, CONCAT('{ "array": [',
               GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('{"degree_name": "',
                                   d.degree_name,
                                   '", "degree": "',
                                   d.degree,
                                   '"}'
                            ) separator ','),
               ']}') As details
FROM details d
        INNER JOIN users u
            ON FIND_IN_SET(u.id, d.user_id) > 0
GROUP BY u.id;
```

This query will provide the answer as expected. Just need a little over head to json parse records after getting results.